# Ошибка после некоторого времени работы скрипта

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Как убрать такую ошибку? Потому что приходится нажимать CRL+C и запускать скрипт заново. Может, таймаут выставить нужно?

```
uname -a

Linux indexoid 4.9.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.25-1kali1 (2017-05-04) x86_64 GNU/Linu

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "katush_replay_pro.py", line 854, in <module>
    Telegram.typing()
  File "katush_replay_pro.py", line 630, in typing
    Telegram_Updater.bot.sendChatAction(chat_id=TELEGRAM_ID, action=Action.ChatAction.TYPING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_telegram_bot-6.0.3-py2.7.egg/telegram/bot.py", line 125, in decorator
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_telegram_bot-6.0.3-py2.7.egg/telegram/bot.py", line 158, in decorator
    return Bot._message_wrapper(self, url, data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_telegram_bot-6.0.3-py2.7.egg/telegram/bot.py", line 146, in _message_wrapper
    result = self._request.post(url, data, timeout=kwargs.get('timeout'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_telegram_bot-6.0.3-py2.7.egg/telegram/utils/request.py", line 252, in post
    **urlopen_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_telegram_bot-6.0.3-py2.7.egg/telegram/utils/request.py", line 176, in _request_wrapper
    raise TimedOut()
telegram.error.TimedOut: Timed out
```

Comment: В чем суть вопроса?

Comment: Ну интернет у вас глючит, ну бывает